# PrestaShop: How to get a ProductListingLazyArray out of my products

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I'm pretty new to PrestaShop - so sry if i ask basic thing

I'm currently working on a module which should display products you chose in the backend as additional section in the default products template - like "highly recommended products"

I finish the whole Backend part, and get the ID's as an array of the chosen products.

As I mentioned I wanna use the default templates which are available after a fresh installation and what I found is placed here `themes\classic\templates\catalog\_partials\products.tpl`.

Now my big problem is: I'm not able to get the data like it should be ...

If I debug e.g. the products which are displayed in the default search behaviour (this uses this template too) I see something like

```php
object(PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Presenter\Product\ProductListingLazyArray)#323 (11) { ["imageRetriever":"Pr .....
```

but as I get my products with

```php
new Product($productId, true);
```

it is no ProductListingLazyArray ... its just an array with products ... and i dont see anything in the frontend (of course I dont, cause e.g. `{$product.id_product}` doesnt look like this in my array ...

Have you any ideas what I can do to "transform" my array of products to an ProductListingLazyArray ??
Or is my thinking wrong ?

THANKS to you all!

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer below and accept it, don't post it into the question.

Comment: Sorry - of course I change it :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Solution**
I just "faked" a search and check if the data is in my array:

```php
/**
 * creates relevant product information for frontend output
 * 
 * @param array $allSelectedProductIds array with all id's of the selected products 
 * @param int $languageId language id of the shop you are in
 * 
 * @return array all product information we need for our frontend rendering
 */
public function getFrontendProductInformation($allSelectedProductIds, $languageId)
{
    // set default category Home
    $category = new Category((int)2);

    // create new product search proider
    $searchProvider = new CategoryProductSearchProvider(
        $this->context->getTranslator(),
        $category
    );

    // set actual context
    $context = new ProductSearchContext($this->context);

    // create new search query
    $query = new ProductSearchQuery();
    $query->setResultsPerPage(PHP_INT_MAX)->setPage(1);
    $query->setSortOrder(new SortOrder('product', 'position', 'asc'));

    $result = $searchProvider->runQuery(
        $context,
        $query
    );

    // Product handling - to get relevant data
    $assembler = new ProductAssembler($this->context);
    $presenterFactory = new ProductPresenterFactory($this->context);
    $presentationSettings = $presenterFactory->getPresentationSettings();
    $presenter = new ProductListingPresenter(
        new ImageRetriever(
            $this->context->link
        ),
        $this->context->link,
        new PriceFormatter(),
        new ProductColorsRetriever(),
        $this->context->getTranslator()
    );

    $products = array();
    foreach ($result->getProducts() as $rawProduct) {
        $productId = $rawProduct['id_product'];
        if(in_array($productId, $allSelectedProductIds)) {
            $product = $presenter->present(
                $presentationSettings,
                $assembler->assembleProduct($rawProduct),
                $this->context->language
            );
            array_push($products, $product);
        }
    }

    return $products;
}
```